# How to obtain this exponential martingale? A question concerning a paper from Stroock and Varadhan

Tags: stochastic-processes

In page 364 of the article Diffusion processes with continuous coefficients I (Stroock Varadhan - 1969), one finds in lemma 3.5:

[image]

[image]

The question is: how do we prove that
$$ Y^s_\theta(t) = \exp \big\{ \langle \theta, \eta(t)\rangle - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t \langle \theta, \sigma^*(u) a(u) \sigma(u)\rangle \, du \big\} ?$$
**Attempt **
In the proof of lemma 3.5 one reads
[image]

So we come back to theorem 3.2
[image]

Now we try to see how to obtain the martingale property of 
$$ Y^s_\theta(t) = \exp \big\{ \langle \theta, \eta(t)\rangle - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t \langle \theta, \sigma^*(u) a(u) \sigma(u)\rangle \, du \big\} $$

as a consequence of Theorem 3.2

First we note that

$$\langle \theta, \eta(t) \rangle = \sum_{j} \theta_j  \eta_j(t) $$

but since $\eta(t) = \int_s^t\sigma(u)d \xi(u)$

$$ \eta_j(t) = \sum_k \int_s^t \sigma_{j,k}(u) d\xi_k(u)$$ so

$$ \langle \theta, \eta(t) \rangle = \sum_j \sum_k \theta_j\int_s^t  \sigma_{j,k}(u) d\xi_k(u) \\
 = \sum_k \int_s^t \sum_j \sigma*_{k,j}(u)\theta_j d\xi_k(u)\\
 = \sum_k \int_s^t  (\sigma*(u)\theta)_k d\xi_k(u)\\
$$

So applying theorem 3.2 we get
$$ Y^s_\theta(t) = \exp \big\{ \langle \theta, \eta(t)\rangle - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t \langle \sigma^*(u)\theta,  a(u) \sigma^*(u)\theta\rangle \, du \big\}\\
= \exp \big\{ \langle \theta, \eta(t)\rangle - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t \langle \theta, \sigma(u) a(u) \sigma^*(u)\theta\rangle \, du \big\} $$

So this result is a bit different than what is stated in theorem 3.2.

Is this a typo?

Comment: @Zachary: Can you please stop editing so many old questions at the same time? It floods the front page and other newer questions won't get attention.

Comment: @Rahul I'll stop now, I'll do more later. I got a little carried away.